# Extjs only apply filter of store in one column of grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a store that is being used in multiple columns of a grid. And only on one column I would like to apply the store filter. When I set the store filter in that specific column, the filter is also being applied in the other columns.

How do I make the filter only work on one column?

Right now it's done in the column like this:

```
store: {
    type: 'myStore',
    filter: {
       filterFn: someFunction
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code you've tried? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: A grid is assigned a store, not a column. Fields are assigned to columns. So when applying a filter to the store, it is applied to all records of a store... So if you filter on x=10 and you have 200 records with only 100 of them having x=10 you will only get those 10 records. I'm not sure how you intend "only on one column" since filters are applied to a store.